# how to get kendo ui scheduler resources selected value from javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui scheduler with a few resources.  I have apply some logic when saving a new event based of the value selected in these resources.
...
var agentId = $("#ToDoAgent").val();

var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

var rsc1= scheduler.resources[1].dataSource;

Answer (score 0):

You can access your model to grab that value on save event, here is some sample

```
function onEventSave(e) {
    var model = e.event; // in this model you can see selected resource value

    if(model.resource_1_ID === 1) {
      ....
    } 
}
```